# Where to find the source code for the research paper "Attention is all you need"?

Tags: transformer, attention

I am reading "Attention is all you need". I have seen the following link:

[image]

Source: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf

But when I go to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor, there are too many folders without a guide. Where do you find the source code for the research paper "Attention is all you need"?

Answer (score 2):

You may find the code related to the paper at https://paperswithcode.com/paper/attention-is-all-you-need.